# Is there a way to track how many times a cookie has been set on all visitors?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a page that sets 1 of 3 different cookies depending on what image you see 1st (Which is random).

Cookie 1: set by the function `RedImage();`

Cookie 2: '' `White Image();`

Cookie 3: '' `Blue Image();`

I'd like to know how many users got the Red Image vs how many people got the Blue Image or White Image. But I don't have access to those numbers because the cookies live on the users' browsers.

I thought about increasing a different cookie's value, but each user would not have access to the other users' created cookie, so the value to increment will not be correct

Does anyone know what I'm talking about? Is this enough information?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you can do client-side, you'd need to write a server implementation to keep track of this. Like you said, users don't have access to cookies that other users created. But if you set up a server that gets hit the first time someone sees an image (you can use the cookie to determine if this is the case), then you can keep track of how many people have seen each image there.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this purely on the client. You will need some kind of server-side storage where you are persisting these values.

Assuming that you had an HTTP endpoint `/countImage.php`, in your JS, you would make an AJAX request to that endpoint like so (using jQuery, in your `RedImage()` function):

```
$.get('countImage.php?color=red', {
  error: function(e){},
  success: function(res){
    // res is response from server
  }
})
```

The example `countImage.php` script that the above code is calling would write a record in a database, and finding out the total number of hits would be as simple as counting the records. You *could* accomplish this on the filesystem, creating a new file for every hit, but that is not a very robust solution for any significant amount of traffic and quickly becomes a maintenance nightmare.

Your problem is one of collecting info across dynamic page views in one centralized place, and one that has been solved before. You may be able to utilize something like Google Analytics [virtual page tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages).